# What files are required after using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

I ran composer in order to use guzzle. It resulted in these directories:

```
    composer
    gabrieldarezzo
    guzzlehttp
    psr
    ralouphie
    symfony
```

I noticed the file car.png in the gabrieldarezzo/colorizzar/. That whole directory seemed useless for guzzle so I deleted it and the code still works. I tried deleting some of the other directories, one at a time, but to code failed. Is there a way to know which files are actually required?

Edited after comments:

The purpose of this question is to ask if all of the files composer adds are necessary. I re-ran composer to a new location and it installed version 6.5.8. The gabrieldarezzo was not included so I must have ran composer for some other package at some point. From all of the replies I can see that the answer to my question is yes, they are required. I appreciate all of the replies to this.

Comment: Composer provides a file named autoload.php which requires all the necessary dependencies for it. You still need to require the packages for example by constructing the class for library X and/or requiring the namespace.

Comment: How does your `composer.json` look like? As a general rule I wouldn't manually delete stuff that were installed by package manager.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the maintainers of Guzzle add random files to their library that serve no purpose? Think about _your_ own code. I'm sure you can potentially remove many files without breaking your app but, what's the point?

Comment: fyi, guzzle doesn't add that `colorizzar` thing (see [repo](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/composer.json#L53)).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I ran composer again to a different location and the directory I mentioned was not present so I must have mixed installs. I'm trying to write a package to use the abuseipdb API. I want to be able to distribute it once done. Since the vendor directory is over 1 MB I thought I would delete any unnecessary files, thus the purpose of this post.

Comment: @user3052443: There is no one-size-fits-it-all answer to the problem. It depends on the libraries and their packaging for Composer. I've left an extended answer, IMHO this depends on how far you want to go. And perhaps Guzzle as a dependency can be replaced (not that its entirely bad or something) as the Web-API you want to make use of can use different HTTP client implementations? Just an additional idea.

Comment: And can you share with your question what command line exactly you did run in order to use guzzle? Which version was installed?

Comment: If your aim is to distribute your own code depending on Guzzle, you shouldn't be distributing your own copy of Guzzle; just distribute a package that lists Guzzle as a dependency, and let users install their own copy, which maybe they already have for other reasons anyway.

Comment: @hakre The command I used is composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle. It installed version 6.5.8. I'm new to using composer. I'm just used to requiring some class file to have some function work. The 169 files added with this seems  unnecessary but, apparently from the posts here, it is common and the accepted practice.

Comment: @user3052443 Thanks. Please add the info to your question (edit it in), so the context is more clear. And yes, you require a package, and that package and all its dependencies (other packages) is being installed (into the vendor folder). Was it at the first time those packages weren't in the `vendor`  folder but in your project directory directly? That part was also unclear to me reading your question and the comments.

Answer (score 2):

> That whole directory seemed useless for guzzle so I deleted it and the code still works.

This statement is meaningless without talking about *what* code still worked - in other words, which files are required depends on what you're actually doing.

If you ask Composer to install Guzzle and then write a PHP file that just says `echo 'Hello world';` then you could delete the whole of the vendor directory, and clearly nothing would break. Or you could write `echo \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS;` and delete everything except for `vendor/guzzle/guzzlehttp/src/RequestOptions.php` where that constant is defined.

> Is there a way to know which files are actually required?

In theory, you could statically analyze a piece of code, recursively identifying which pieces of code were reachable, and therefore what the minimum set of files used would be. You could also monitor a running application and see which files it opened, at the PHP autoloader level or even at the OS / file system level.

But the question is **why do you care?**

It's important to understand that no file will actually be read and loaded into memory unless it is referenced in some way. This is the purpose of [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). So deleting files will not make any difference to the *compilation* or *execution* speed of your application.

Deleting the files will reduce the *disk space* needed to store the application, but it would be rare for the space involved to be a significant proportion of what you have available. It would also reduce the *bandwidth* needed to deploy it, but source code generally compresses well, so once bundled into something like a tar.gz, this saving is generally also insignificant.

A final note which might be relevant is that *none of these files should be committed in your version history*. You should commit `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, and mark the entirety of the `vendor` directory as "ignored" (e.g. in a `.gitignore` file). You can then get the exact dependencies used by any version by running `composer install`, which reads the versions from `composer.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you require third-party packages without deeply reviewing and track-listing every single file with cryptographically secure content hashes of the reviews outcome, you can easily run into the situation you describe.

The problem with "randomly" deleting such directories is that it does not replace proper dependency checking, but merely prevents the (now removed) code from being loaded onto production systems to be analysed and executed in memory (or in the case of the `car.png` for some other reason?).

Now between those two poles there is a lot of room and commonly development projects and the people running them aren't important enough that dependencies actually get reviewed thoroughly albeit most of them come without fitness for a particular purpose and a disclaimer in very bold letters.

However if that is a project you look into and you find that some files look fishy, report the issue to the project if you care and it means something to you.

Sometimes projects do not make (extended) use of the [`dist` distribution of a Composer Package (concept)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package) and there is room for improvement (it should go without saying that this is with no judgement of any of those projects practices). E.g. to exclude development resources in production use. This has the benefit that you don't need to remove files "randomly" but you cooperate with actual developers and software distributors.